# How can I block all x-rated Twitter-profiles from following me?

Tags: twitter

I get lots of followers for some reason who are women with really sleazy profiles and I am getting sick of having to see it and block them.

Is there a way I can just set my profile to totally block all x-rated profiles? I can also tell that a lot of them are spam and it's just getting out of hand. I thought it wasn't suppose to be like that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I can just set my profile to totally block all x-rated profiles? I can also tell that a lot of them are spam and it's just getting out of hand. I thought it wasn't suppose to be like that.

Twitter doesn't provide you a way to do so, so no that's not possible right now